# Can f(n) be in big O and big Omega of g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a question about one of my homework questions. I've watched a couple videos on youtube explaining Big O, Theta, Omega etc but I do not understand what this question is asking.

[image: Question]

What is this question asking? There is no function that exists that is less than or equals to its complexity as its upper bound and where it is greater than its omega but is a lower bound?

I am at a complete loss and pretty confused. If someone could clear up the confusion by explanation, that would be fantastic. I cannot wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question is asking you to prove or disprove the statement. When it comes to asymptotic notation using the less than/equal/greater than symbols can be confusing for new learners because it kind of implies an equation between the two when really it saying an entirely different thing.

*O(g(n))* is actually a *set* of functions that is bounded above by *g(n)* times some constant factor for large enough *n*. In math you would say *f(n) ≤ O(g(n))* implies *f(n) ≤ c g(n)* for *c>0, n>N*. That is the reason ≤ is used for O. [Big-Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) is defined similarly but as a lower bound. There are many functions that can satisfy an upper and lower bound which is the reason why it's defined as a set.

So it might be more clear to use set notation for this. You can express the same thing as:

```
f(n) ∈ O(g(n))
f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))
```

So *f(n) ≤ O(g(n))* means the same as *f(n) = O(g(n))* which is the same as *f(n) ∈ O(g(n))*. And *f(n) ≥ Ω(g(n))* means the same as *f(n) = Ω(g(n))* which is the same as *f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))*.

So what's it's really asking you to prove is whether you can have a function *f(n)* that is bounded above and below by *g(n)*.

You can. This is actually the definition for Big-Theta. *Ө(g(n))* is the set of all functions such that *g(n)* is an asymptotic upper and lower bound on those functions. In other words, *h(n) = Ө(g(n))* implies *c₁ g(n) ≤ h(n) ≤ c₂ g(n)* for large enough *n*.

If *f(n) = 7n^2 + 500* then a suitable upper and lower bound can be *n^2* because *f(n) ≥ 1*n^2* and *f(n) ≤ 8*n^2* for all *n > 10*. Therefore *f(n) ∈ Ө(n^2)*.

Comment: Thank you so much! That made a lot more sense and yeah, the question was to discuss aka prove or disapprove. I am a beginner and this question kinda stumped me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Question on the last line - For n  = 11 I get f(n) = 7n^2+500 = 1347 and g(n) = 8n^2 = 968
Either 8 or 11 has to be larger for f(n) to be less than or equal to g(n)?